# JavaScript in the head tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file which looks like this.

```
<head>

    <script>
        document.onready
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Works";
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="demo">
    </div>
</body>
```

When I put the script tags at the bottom of the page, everything works fine. But when I put the script in `<head></head` tag, it does not work. I guess it is not able to access elements that are below the script.

On many sites like StackOverflow, JavaScript is in head tag. How is it then able to access HTML elements that are below it?

What should I do now? Should I just move my script to the bottom or is there a way by which JavaScript can access elements below it?

Comment: I doubt that Javascript works anywhere...

Comment: If you put your JavaScript just before the </body> ending tag, you don't have to worry about telling it to wait until the document is ready. I have all my Javascript, both inline (not a great idea in my view) and external JS files in this position without document ready code and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Works"; }, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get `document.onready` from? That would **never work**.

To ensure the page is loaded, you could use `window.onload`;

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Works";
}
```

Comment: `onload` is overkill, aim for `DOMContentLoaded` or checking `document.readyState` instead, thats soon enough to access the DOM.

Comment: @jAndy Sure, that's also valid. But in order to illustrate the point more clearly, I simply used `onload`. It's perfectly fine in this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
document.ready= function () {
  //code to run when page loaded
}

window.onload = function () {
  //code to run when page AND images loaded
}
```

Comment: then why did the syntax work when I put the script at the end of the document?